# Scraper : How do we download the image within Div Class that has url openning the image

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

How do we capture the image that has the following code ? since it is different from general format where i only capture the src and img.

```
<div class="avatar" style="background-image: 
url(customavatars/545/5453285_1410924046.jpg);background-size: cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center;width: 120px;height: 120px;border-radius: 70px;margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;" onmouseover="showUserInfoBox('userinfo234340519')" onmouseout="clearShowUserInfoTimer()"></div>
```

Original web site
Visit https://mobile.uwants.com/viewthread.php?tid=19780494&extra=page%3D1

The image : Visit https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkbHk.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since the image you want to get is defined as a css background, you'll need to extract the contents of the `style` attribute, and parse the css you get from that.

You can try to do this yourself, but it would probably be easier to use an existing library, such as [cssutils](https://pythonhosted.org/cssutils/) or [tinycss2](https://pythonhosted.org/tinycss2/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re_first()`

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="avatar"]/@style').re_first(r'url\([^\)]+')
```